# -ne as an Indication of Fear in a Question

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-choice, word-comparison, enclitic

I was recently taking a sort of multiple choice quiz on just general Latin knowledge, and I came upon one question that threw me for a loop, so to speak. The question asked which of the options best described the differences between the question words -*ne*, *nonne*, and *num*. Using process of elimination, I found that there was only one answer where *nonne* was expecting an affirmative answer and *num* was expecting a negative answer. The problem was, however, that -*ne* was labelled as being used to express fear in the question. I have never really thought of using -*ne* in this way, and a quick lookup of the enclitic in [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DN%3Aentry%20group%3D6%3Aentry%3Dne2) reveals just what I thought: that -*ne* was used for a question expecting a yes or no answer, or for emphasis. The word *ne* (negative of *ut*) can be used for fear clauses, but the question specifically had the enclitic form -*ne*. -*ne* is also used to add emphasis to a question, so one can see how this could be translated to fear in some way, but this seems rather a broad stroke to paint if one is trying to point out the distinctions between each of the words.

Therefore, my question is: **can the enclitic -*ne* add specific connotations of fear to a question, and if so, are there examples of this in classical literature?**

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't referring to cases like *timeo ne + subj.*?

Comment: @brianpck Like I said in the question, it specifically asked about -_ne_ in reference to questions. It would be rather odd if they actually meant _ne_ in reference to questions.

Comment: It sounds to me like the maker of this "quiz" misread a grammar book or just doesn't know what he's talking about. But I'd be happy to be proven wrong!

Answer (score 5):

The quiz seems to be wrong.
The triplet *nonne*, *num*, *-ne* is indeed important for Latin questions, and therefore naturally studied together.
It seems that at some point the author of the quiz mistook *-ne* for *ne* — perhaps they looked at the wrong dictionary entry by accident.
And even for *ne* it is a case of overinterpretation; the conjunction has many uses and is used also for many subordinate clauses expressing fear, but the word itself does not imply fear.
I would say that *ne* has a connection to fear, *-ne* does not, but neither expresses fear in itself.

I have never seen *-ne* expressing fear not seen any grammar or dictionary mention it.
If I wanted to make a fearful question, I would specifically use one of the other two words mentioned: *Num leo me edet?* *Nonne pater revertatur?*
Using *-ne* makes the question neutral, whereas in case of fear one type of answer is expected or hoped.

It is possible that there are ways to use *-ne* to indicate fear.
Even if such examples are found, that is very rare and makes a silly question for a quiz.
The main role of *-ne* in questions as opposed to those of *nonne* and *num* is quite clear and has nothing to do with fear.

Comment: And, even though *ne* is used in clauses of fearing, the conjunction itself does not indicate fear at all.

Comment: @Anonym Indeed. I had not worded that quite clearly, so I added some emphasis to it.